# Fully qualified javascript method call

Tags: javascript, wpf

I am working with trying to call some javascript from a client side app.  My javascript was transpiled from ES6 to ES5.

Here is what it looks like transpiled:

```
System.register([], function (_export) {
    var _prototypeProperties, _classCallCheck, Welcome, UpperValueConverter;

    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            "use strict";

            _prototypeProperties = function (child, staticProps, instanceProps) { if (staticProps) Object.defineProperties(child, staticProps); if (instanceProps) Object.defineProperties(child.prototype, instanceProps); };

            _classCallCheck = function (instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } };

            Welcome = _export("Welcome", (function () {
                function Welcome() {
                    _classCallCheck(this, Welcome);

                    this.heading = "Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!";
                    this.firstName = "John";
                    this.lastName = "Doe";
                }

                _prototypeProperties(Welcome, null, {
                    fullName: {
                        get: function () {
                            return "" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
                        },
                        configurable: true
                    },
                    welcome: {
                        value: function welcome() {
                            alert("Welcome, " + this.fullName + "!");
                        },
                        writable: true,
                        configurable: true
                    }
                });

                return Welcome;
            })());
        }
    };
});
```

The method I am trying call is welcome().  It looks like this before being transpiled:

```
export class Welcome{
  constructor(){
    this.heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
    this.firstName = 'John';
    this.lastName = 'Doe';
  }

  get fullName(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  welcome(){
    alert(`Welcome, ${this.fullName}!`);
  }
}

export class UpperValueConverter {
  toView(value){
    return value && value.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

I am calling it in a WPF webBrowser (C#) like this:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("Welcome.welcome");
```

I have also tried just `welcome`, but that does not work either.

I am thinking that to get this to call I am needing some thing else, but I am too new to JavaScript to get it working.

**How would I call the `welcome` function from outside this javascript "class"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`welcome` is declared as an instance method in your ES6 code. You'll need to create an instance of the `Welcome` class before you're able to call the method:

```
var welcome = new Welcome(); 
welcome.welcome();
```

Unfortunately, with a `WebBrowser` control you first need to inject a named method into the global scope to handle that bit of code:

```
var scriptEl = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
var scriptDomElement = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
scriptDomElement.text = "function welcome() { var w = new Welcome(); w.welcome(); }";

var head = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("welcome");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the following:

```
var instance = new Welcome();
instance.welcome(); // performs your alert.
```